# The value arrive after my viewWillAppear: called I need the value before

Tags: objective-c, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

In my A class  when I open the App it calls **viewWillAppear:** and  inside my viewWillAppear: I have an if statement. the problem is the Support_three_ways_call that is a bool value that receive the value directly from the server and when the viewWillAppear finished after 6 seconds the real value arrive from server, I am trying to find a way or to refresh my view after 6 seconds that take the real value and I dont know how to do that, I would like to ask if there are anyway to refresh the view after some seconds or call the same view from another class to make it disappear or appear.   I tried to call my viewWillAppear from another class after 6 seconds but the problem is, it call the function but it doesn't work.

any help appreciate.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];





    if (Support_three_ways_call){
        keypadEditorView.threewaysbutton.hidden = NO;

    } else {

        keypadEditorView.threewaysbutton.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: "after 6 seconds the real value arrive from server" Where? what's the code to get the valu?

Comment: Hi @Larme, Support_three_ways_call is a bool value that arrive from server as XML, as the code very heavy I only wrote the part that I have a problem,i dont have a problem with value.

Comment: How do you get your server value? In what class? Are you using a closure to tell your viewcontroller ? a NSNotification ? Do NOT call yourself `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: I get the value from Class B and then with global variable I pass the value to class A in order to hide the button or not.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add a `supportsThreeWayCalls` declared property to `A`.

Step 2: Write a custom setter `-supportsThreeWayCalls:` to the implementation.

Step 3: Inside the custom setter set the hidden property of the button as you do.

Step 4: Set this property from $whereyoureceivetheresponse.